# Inserting image in Word

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to insert a generated QR Code image in the word document but the image is not showing properly:

[image]

My code:

```js
function insertImage() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        $('#output').qrcode({
            text: $("#txtData").val(),
            render: "canvas",
            background: "#ffffff",
            foreground: "#000000",
            width: 150,
            height: 150
        });
        var canvas = $('#output canvas');
        console.log(canvas);
        var img = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");

        $("#output").attr("src", img); //QR Code image generated on the task pane

        var imgHtml = "<img " + "src='" + img + "' />";

        // Code that insert the QR image in the document
        Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(imgHtml, {
                coercionType: "html"
            },
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                    writeError('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: try converting the image to base 64 and adding it as a string

Comment: @JohnHogan the image is already in base64

Comment: @KimBrandl done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing a two different API conventions here. You don't use a `run` context when using the [Shared API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/shared-api), it is only used when calling the [Word API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview). In general, I would recommend using Word API as it's newer and overall provides a more functionality.

That said, for this operation you could use either Word or Shared APIs. I'll provide examples for both.

Also note that `.toDataURL()` returns a string that *includes* a base64 image. It isn't a pure base64 representation. You need to remove the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix before Word will be able to render it.

**Shared API:**

Since you're simply inserting an image, I would use `Office.CoercionType.Image` instead of `Office.CoercionType.Html`:

```js
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(imgHtml, {
        coercionType: "image"
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
            writeError('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    });
```

**Word API:**

The Word API includes a [`insertInlinePictureFromBase64`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range#insertinlinepicturefrombase64base64encodedimage-string-insertlocation-string) method. As with the `setSelectedDataAsync`, it takes an image in as a Base 64 encoded string:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(base64String, "end");
    return context.sync();
}).catch(function (myError) {
    // Handle error
})
```

Comment: it works now, you have no idea how grateful i am to you Mr Marc.